# Eloquent Javavascript, Chapter 11 (Asynchronous Programming), Question on path finding algorithm

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, routes, dijkstra

I'm having a problem understanding a line of code from Eloquent Javascript ebook, [Chapter 11](https://eloquentjavascript.net/11_async.html) (Message Routing section). In it the author tries to explain how message routing in a supposed network might work (by incorporating promises and other async concepts). He constructs different types of functions that handle different actions (sending request, receiving it, responding,...). But then there is this implementation of route finding algorithm that I think I don't quite understand.

```
//SECTION THAT CREATES A KIND OF NEIGHBOUR MAP THAT EVERY NEST (COMPUTER) HAS 

requestType("connections", (nest, {name, neighbors},
                            source) => {
  let connections = nest.state.connections;
  if (JSON.stringify(connections.get(name)) ==
      JSON.stringify(neighbors)) return;
  connections.set(name, neighbors);
  broadcastConnections(nest, name, source);
});

function broadcastConnections(nest, name, exceptFor = null) {
  for (let neighbor of nest.neighbors) {
    if (neighbor == exceptFor) continue;
    request(nest, neighbor, "connections", {
      name,
      neighbors: nest.state.connections.get(name)
    });
  }
}

everywhere(nest => {
  nest.state.connections = new Map();
  nest.state.connections.set(nest.name, nest.neighbors);
  broadcastConnections(nest, nest.name);
});

//PATH FINDING FUNCTION
function findRoute(from, to, connections) {
  let work = [{at: from, via: null}];
  for (let i = 0; i < work.length; i++) {
    let {at, via} = work[i];
    for (let next of connections.get(at) || []) {
      if (next == to) return via;
      if (!work.some(w => w.at == next)) {
        work.push({at: next, via: via || next});
      }
    }
  }
  return null;
}

//THEN THERE ARE FUNCTIONS THAT HANDLE THE ACTUAL MESSAGE SENDING/ROUTING

function routeRequest(nest, target, type, content) {
  if (nest.neighbors.includes(target)) {
    return request(nest, target, type, content);
  } else {
    let via = findRoute(nest.name, target,
                        nest.state.connections);
    if (!via) throw new Error(`No route to ${target}`);
    return request(nest, via, "route",
                   {target, type, content});
  }
}

requestType("route", (nest, {target, type, content}) => {
  return routeRequest(nest, target, type, content);
});
```

My question is, in the findRoute function, why is there || [] in the inner for loop? Is it there for appropriate consequent error handling (in case somehow there is no nest specified as having neighbours in the connections property, but is regardless of that listed as someones neighbouring nest)?

Comment: `connections.get(at)` may return null or undefined, depending on the api, and you can't do a `for...of` loop over null or undefined, so he replaces that value with an empty array in that case

Comment: thank you for your reply, it helped :)

Answer (score 0):

`connections.get(at)` may return null or undefined, depending on the api, and you can't do a `for...of` loop over null or undefined, so he replaces that value with an empty array in that case